# Use one SQL Connection with multiple transactions

Tags: sql, vb.net, transactions

I have a vb.net web app and I am passing a SQL connection and a transaction to a method which writes a single record to the database.

I would like to start and commit a transaction for each record that is written but using the same sql connection until the loop is done.

One method I saw was utilizing a using statement but it didn't work for me.it runs the first time and gives an error on the second that the transaction has already been commited

```
Using sqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
  sqlConnection.Open()
  Using transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

      For Each user In users
         Try
            myDataWriteMethod(user, conn, tr)

         Catch ex As Exception
            tranaction.rollback()
         End Try
         transaction.commit()
      Next 
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: Besides the answer to your question, you're error handling is never going to work correctly - you'll rollback the transaction, exit the `Try` block, then try to commit that same transaction. If you're wanting to commit each loop iteration individually, move the commit inside the `Try` block, as the last statement before the `Catch` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are committing or rolling back the transaction at each step of the for loop. You probably need to either (1) begin a new transaction for each user, e.g.,

```
Using sqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
  sqlConnection.Open()
  For Each user In users
      Using transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
      ...
```

or (2) only commit or rollback the transaction at the end, e.g.

```
Using sqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
  sqlConnection.Open()
  Using transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

      Try
          For Each user In users
              myDataWriteMethod(user, conn, tr)
          Next
      Catch ex As Exception
          tranaction.rollback()
      End Try

      transaction.commit()
  End Using
End Using
```

Note that I'm not a VB.NET programmer so my syntax may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks... one additional question if you could help I get en error when the code is executed twice such as two users using the application at the same time "SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions."

Comment: @Adonis L: Could you somehow be reusing the SqlConnection you create or attempting to open a new transaction before committing the current transaction?

Comment: I don't believe so, it runs fine when one user executes but when there are concurrent users it fails, the using statement should open a new connection for each user

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want.

```
Using sqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    sqlConnection.Open()
    For Each user In users
        Using transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
            Try
                myDataWriteMethod(user, conn, tr)
                transaction.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                transaction.Rollback()
            End Try
        End Using
    Next   
End Using
```